# Is it possible to integrate different parameters/styles/images/code in the same apk?

Tags: java, android, apk, updates

I know the question is not self explanatory, so let me elaborate.

I have an application that I offer to my clients, for now they work the same, they just have differences in the icon, images, colors and some string parameters such as the app name, the particular link to the webservice, a code used to check for updates, etc.

I have them in different projects, I make the changes in one and merge those changes to the rest, I generate the apks and then upload them to the server for update.

I'm thinking that this in the long term is not very efficient, because if I eventually get 100, 1000 clients the work of updating something it's gonna be a really long and tedious process.

In addition to that, some clients can ask to add a particular feature to the app so that's something else to have in mind.

I'd like to know if it's possible to work with 1 project only without sacrificing customization:

- I was thinking of retrieving the particular parameters from a database the first time the user opens the app and login but I don't think thats enough for all the media resources, including the customized icon
- Regarding the particular features I thought about downloading them and replacing the default files but I don't think that's even possible
- So I thought about keeping all the scripts in the code but that might be insecure and a waste of space considering the majority of users will not use those.

I'm relatively new to android so I don't know if I'm missing other options, so that's why I'm asking to you what's best and where to learn to implement them, hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this will cover most of your use cases
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic doesn't that requires the app to be in google play? I don't have my apps there

Comment: It should work like FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) - You don't need to publish your app to GP in order to receive notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is flavors. You have a pretty good documentation in Android docs. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Take into account that this allows customization of lots of different things for each variant: resources, variables in Gradle scripts, even code.

Comment: This is definitely way to go if you have small number of flavors, but i think this will not help OP much if he gets to 20 customers and thus 20 flavors he needs to maintain

Comment: I maintain an app with 46 flavors and it's no problem.  As long as the flavor-specific stuff doesn't change often, it's not really a maintenance burden. It sounds like all he needs in the flavors is the sort of thing that doesn't change much.  Now, if each client starts wanting different behavior, that can become problematic, but of course it would be no matter what technique you use.

Comment: @nasch yeah, I already have one customer that requires an extra input in a form that at the same time determines the behaviour of other things

Comment: Anyway, those particular behaviours can be just a bunch of cases.
its much better to handle those in different projects than 100's

Comment: Agreed, you're right to want to make a change.  And as Xavier said, java classes can be specific to a flavor as well.  The only problem there is that if you do that, then every flavor has to have a copy, or you'll get a duplicate class error.

Comment: You're right. There is a workaround though, which is by changing the sourceSet for all the flavors except the one that is different. So, for example, flavor1, flavor2 and flavor3 will have the same sourceSet (pointing to the same directory, let's call it "common") and flavor4 will keep its own specific directory https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#configure-sourcesets

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your situation is to make your app as dynamic as you can. You have to put all the things on server like icons, strings, color codes, images everything. And for each screen you have to pull all those things from server and show in your app.
You have to create an admin panel or you can change the data directly into your database. You have to create a unique admin user for each app, where you will upload the data and app will get the data with user id, that means your app will need authentication as well.

If I am not mistaken you are willing to create something like the app in link given below:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xpous.myapps&hl=en

If this is the case, then you need to do a-lot of hard-work. Because that's a huge empire to build.

Comment: It's much simpler to just make a build flavor for each client.

Comment: Indeed this is the better.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to divide your project into modules.

In this way you could centralize your core functionalities into single reusable (core) module, and later on include it as dependency in every new module you will create for each customer.

This approach can also be tricky to maintain, but with some gradle tasks and good branching (with CI/CD pipelines) this would be my way to go.

A bit of topick, but something like this can get you going:

in your app build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.my.app'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1003
        versionName '0.1.3'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            //Dummy
            storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", '"http://my_api.com/"'

            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Awesome App", appNameSuffix: ""]
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true

            buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "http://my_api_staging.com/"'

            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Awesome App", appNameSuffix: ".Development"]
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " Debug"
        }
    }
}
```

in Manifest

```
 <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="${appName}${appNameSuffix}"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

At build time your manifest placeholders will be replaced with values provided in gradle file.

Also you will be able to access fields that you declared. 
For example lets take API_URL.

You could specify different api url for every customer you have and later use it like:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                    .build();
```